# Backbone.js with custom events in VIEW (events from another library)?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, steroids

So I am using steroids.js and the library provides me with this event:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onVisibilityChange, false);

function onVisibilityChange() {

}
```

This works if I just put it in my JS file, but how does that translate in a View with Backbone.js? How I implement this with the framework? I tried with .on in the initialize function, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1 - Using `document` as an element:

```
var DocumentEventsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el : document,
  events : {
    'visibilitychange' : 'onVisibilityChange'
  },
  onVisibilityChange : function () {
    console.log('inside onVisibilityChange');
  }
});

// test
new DocumentEventsView();
$(document).trigger('visibilitychange');
```

#### 2 - Using custom `el`:

```
var DocumentEventsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize : function () {
    $(document).on('visibilitychange', _.bind(this.onVisibilityChange, this));
  },
  onVisibilityChange : function () {
    console.log('inside onVisibilityChange');
  }
});

// test
new DocumentEventsView();
$(document).trigger('visibilitychange')
```

Comment: This looks good. But I don't get the _.bind(this.onVisibilityChange, this) part. Why not just $(document).on('visibilitychange', 'onVisibilityChange', this)) ?

Comment: @Maxwell jQuery `.on` method does not accept a context argument. Using bind, the `this` inside the method will reference the `View` this, not the jQuery object. This is to make the behavior consistent with the usual `events` binding in Backbone.

Comment: I know sorry, I put an extra argument at the end, I could not edit my comment for five minutes haha. What I don't uderstand is the underscore method, what is it for? Why can't we just put the onVisibilityChange method right away instead of using the undserscore method?

Comment: @Maxwell because in this case you lose View context, `this` inside `onVisibilityChange` method will reference to the `document`.

Answer (score 1):

If a view have the `document` as `view.el`, then you could listen to custom DOM events using the [`events` hash](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend).

If not, then you can listen to an event manually in the `initialize` method.

```
initialize: function() {
    $(document).on("visibilitychange", _.bind(this.hanldeVisibility, this));
}
```

This will work, so if it haven't for you, it can be a race condition (check any async behavior, etc).

On an important side note. It is really important to clear custom binded events once your view is removed. This is usually handle this way:

```
remove: function() {
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
    $(document).off("visibilitychange");
}
```

If you do not clean your events after, you'll create memory leaks. And this could eventually crash your application.

Comment: So I have to create this function right?
Backbone.View.prototype.remove

Comment: No, by extending the View, you'll run your method when the view is removed, and not `Backbone.View.prototype.remove`. You just want to run the default method too. The `remove` method I showed in my answer is 100% functionnal like this.